# Wordpress 'Order By' not working

Tags: php, wordpress

To start, I spent about 3 hours reading and trying different solutions so I want you to know that I didn't jump straight into asking this question.

I took over a website that has "Custom Fields"->"Fields Groups" setup for faculty.

The original code is :

```
  query_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'post_type' => 'faculty',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  ))
```

I replaced it with

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'faculty',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'sort_field',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And tried a bunch of variations without any luck.  To be clear, my goal is to add sorting to the faculty "field group" and my approach is to add a field called 'sort_field' where they could type in a number and then this sql query would return the result in the correct order.

Here is the result of  var_dump($query->request);

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sort_field' ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'faculty' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC LIMIT 0, 100"
```

Edit :

I tried redoing my approach using Jordi's link

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'faculty',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'sort_field',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
print_r($posts);
```

I get no results

Comment: Looks like your site uses ACF. Have you checked [ACF | Order posts by custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/)?

Comment: When you say "not working" can you elaborate? Do you get an error? Does it correctly get posts (but they're not the posts you expect)? It's really hard to help without knowing the context of "not working"...

Comment: Thanks for the question.  The above query returns no results. In other variations that I have tried it simply did not sort at all.

Comment: Thank you Jordi Nebot for your link.  I read through the article and it seems like I am doing exactly what it says in my original question.  Please advise if you would like me to make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since its ACF column you need to name it in query again, and also specific its type. Its bit weird but that's how it is. To name it you use some 'dull' meta query condition which work for all results .

```
$quoteRulesAgs = [
    'post_type' => 'custompost',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    "meta_query" => array(
        "rule_order_custom" => array(
            "key" => "rule_order",
            "compare" => ">=",
            "value" => -100000,
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => [
        'rule_order_custom' => 'ASC'
    ]
];
```

Order by with '**rule_order**' wouldn't work, but work with '**rule_order_custom**' after I typed in some nonsense condition (rule_order column is always > 0), also had to specify type otherwise it would order it as string.